# Issues using 'Related Permissions Module' with v4.6 of CiviCRM. Will there be an upgrade soon?

Tags: webform-civicrm, acl

We are using CiviCRM Webforms to allow parents to sign-up their events for there children. I am restricting access to related contacts using groups but would like to enforce permissions using 'Related Permissions Module', however this does not seem compatible with v4.6. Will there be an upgrade soon

Answer (score 5):

Good question!

It adds fields to the relationship_type form - & the methodology for that broke in 4.5 I believe. So, I believe that if you install the github version Related permissions on 4.6 the relationship type form is likely to, at the very least, need testing. The added fields are the ones that force particular relationship types to always be permissioned. I think the earlier version doesn't offer that functionality & also doesn't require the entity_settings module. If you auto-installed you probably have that earlier version.

The way the fields are added to the form is by declaring it to the entity_setting module - which added them via extra.tpl - but they were winding up outside the form - so the alterContent hook was moving them around in the DOM to an appropriate place. Wasn't much fun & is now broken - but not sure a good way to inject fields into settings forms without doing a tpl override

Answer (score 2):

Although the extension is still listed as v1.2, there have been recent updates to the codebase which have helped us with a conflict with CiviMail in 4.7.10.

Once installed, the info lists compatibility with 4.7 even though the extensions page on civicrm.org only lists up to 4.4.